# What are the conditions for the Intermediate Value Theorem to not be valid in a $[a,b]$ interval?

Tags: real-analysis, rolles-theorem

I came up across an exercise in which $f(x)=|2\sin(x)+\tan(x)-3x|, x \in ({-π\over2},{π\over2})$, and I was asked:

Let ${-π\over2}<α<0<β<{π\over2}$.

If the Intermediate Value theorem is not valid in the $[α,β]$ interval, prove $α=-β$.

In the solutions, the exercise said that for IVT to not be valid, there must be $f(α)=f(β)$. Why is this the case though? Isn't it that if $f(α)=f(β)$, then it's just Rolle's theorem, so again $f'(ξ)=0$? Βut it CAN be implemented?. The conditions for IVT are again, $f$ to be continuous in $[α,β]$, and differentiable in $(α,β)$.

Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is continuous for any described $\alpha, \beta$. This follows because $x \in (0, \pi/2)$ we have that $f$ is strictly increasing which can be shown by differentiation. We have something similar for $x \in (-\pi/2, 0)$. For $x = 0$ the function equals 0. So the function is continuous in the described open interval.

So the only way for the IVT to not be valid is if $f(\alpha) = f(\beta)$ in the interval $[\alpha, \beta]$. This is be definition of the IVT because you can't find any value *between* $f(\alpha) = f(\beta)$.

We can now see that $f(\alpha) = f(-\alpha)$ because $g(x) = 2 sin(x) + tan(x) - 3x$ satisfies $g(-\alpha) = -g(\alpha)$ so that $f(\alpha) = f(-\beta) = |g(-\beta)| = |-g(\beta)| = |g(\beta)| = f(\beta)$.

It follows that if $f(\alpha) = (\beta)$ then $\alpha = - \beta$ because $f(x)$ is strictly increasing above and under $x = 0$.

Comment: What do you mean 'by definition of the IVT'? I see 2 conditions for the IVT to be valid, so I can't understand why $f(a)=f(b)$ must be the case.

Comment: IVT says that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then you can find any given value between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. But if $f(a) = f(b)$ then there is no value between so the IVT is "tautological" in this case. 

As we saw the function was continuous in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and strictly decreasing in $(-\pi/2, 0]$ and strictly increasing in $[0, \pi/2]$. It looks like the letter U and is symmetric around the y-axis with $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: Oh, yeah you are right, wow. Thanks a lot!